# Angular 8: lazy loading with template in root component

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-routing

I have pages-routing.module.ts that have child route like this :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: PagesComponent,
    children: [
    {
      path: 'persons',
      loadChildren: './persons/persons.module#PersonsModule'
    }
   ]
  }
]
```

and in my persons-routing.module.ts my child rout not work properly

my persons-routing,.module.ts is:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
path: '',
component: PersonsComponent,
children: [
  {
    path: 'Test',
    component: TestComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'Sample',
    component: SampleComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'Sample',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
]
  }
]


@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
CommonModule,
RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
RouterModule
  ]
})
```

and I want to open 'SampleComponent' beside the base template in my PersonsComponent when I route to persons

```
<div class="row ml-0">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-2 p-0 person-sidebar">
<nb-card size="small" class="mb-0">

</nb-card>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-7 col-lg-10 pl-0" *ngIf="selectedUser">
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

how can resolve the problem?

Comment: do you same behaviour for TestComponent also?

Comment: @AndrewAllen hi Allen yes I get the same result for TestComponent

Comment: is there an error, or what is the current behavior? if I'm understanding your expected behavior, you need another `router-outlet` possibly going to need to give it a target name

Comment: @karim Angular 8 lazy loading is not like that, you need to use `lazy imports`, unless adding angular 8 in the title is a typo

Comment: This is similar to the to menu or not to menu from the following slides (there's youtube video also) though on it's side- https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1O_WEKlRRT2jp5oCMQmJmU03pf9msX4zuZH_RhBW_Cbs/edit

Comment: @alphapilgrim I have app-routing.module that have a field for lazy loading pages-module and I want to behave the same task with pages and persons in top-level

Comment: @AndrewAllen yes this is